# DragAndDrop with Protractor accross tabs ( or windows )

Tags: selenium, drag-and-drop, protractor, automated-tests

I have 2 different web apps and I need to make automation test which cover this scenario:

I drag a picture from one app and paste it in another tab ( or window ) to other app. 
There is no option to simulate with file upload because there is some logic when picture is dropped how they reference that image in both apps.

I did not find any solution which can drop outside of tab ( window ).

Any ideas?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/drag-drop

Answer (score 0):

you have to create a custom function to meet your goal.

Checkout: https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-dnd

With this package you can drag-drop on the same window, but if you extend the function and create a custom logic, for example:

```
onDragStart - element from window 1
{your logic to switch window}
OnDragEnd - element from window 2
```